# Fails to render Tick Mark (Font: Segoe UI Symbol) using NReco.PDdfGenerator

Tags: c#, nreco

I am using NReco.Pdfgenerator in an Alpine Linux container to convert HTML to PDF. It is failing to convert encoded Symbols like "✔"

Can someone help me understand the problem?

Is it to do with installation of additional font packages? If so, can you help me with the expected list of packages.

Comment: It works fine on the Demo page. The web server where the conversion runs might be equipped with all the necessary fonts. The same tick converts fine for me on Windows. The problem happens only when the conversion happens inside an Alpine Docker Container.